# AS3 bitmapData on nextframe();

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

not a coder so struggling a little here:

Trying to draw current frame in the next frame as a bitmap for cpu efficiency.  In AS2 this code works like a charm:

```
import flash.display.*;
// # create the bitmap
var tBitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 200, true, 0x00000000);

// # now draw this movieClip's content to the bitmap
tBitmapData.draw(this);
// # 2nd frame should be blank!
nextFrame();
// # now attach the bitmap you made to this movieclip
this.attachBitmap(tBitmapData, 1, "auto", true);
```

Just need to know how to re-write this for AS3.  Thank you!

Comment: should a matter of replacing the attachBitmap line with something like: `addChild(new Bitmap(tBitmapData));`

Answer (score 1):

First, in AS3 [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) is not a DisplayObject. You need to wrap it into a [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html) object. Then you replace attachBitmap with addChild as George Profenza mentioned:

```
import flash.display.*;
// # create the bitmap
var tBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 200, true, 0x000000);

// # now draw this movieClip's content to the bitmap
tBitmapData.draw(this);
// # 2nd frame should be blank!
nextFrame();
// # now attach the bitmap you made to this movieclip
this.addChild(new Bitmap(tBitmapData));
```

Also try to type your variables (`var tBitmapData:BitmapData`). This increases performance and allows the compiler to catch some errors.